# Why does converting timezones (and to unix timestamps) behave inconsistently in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I'm parsing and manipulating some dates and times which, for reasons of interoperability with other systems, also need to be stored as UNIX (epoch) timestamps.  In doing so, I'm seeing some weird behavior from pandas' Timestamp.tz_convert(), and then in its Timestamp.strftime() behavior in casting to epoch time, that makes me doubt my understanding of what should be going on.

The times I'm working with are in the US/Eastern timezone, but of course, epoch time is UTC, so my approach had been to *cast* to UTC since most conversions to/from UNIX timestamps assume that a tz-naive DateTime is in UTC.  Let's leave aside whether doing that conversion is absolutely necessary to get valid timestamps; here's what I'm seeing that's problematic:
1. Using Timestamp.tz_convert() to change the timezone representation of a timestamp (i.e., a universal point in time) *also* changes the UNIX timestamp when you convert using Timestamp.strftime().
2. The differences in those timestamps don't even correspond to the proper hour differences between US-Eastern and GMT.

Here's some basic interactive-mode python to illustrate:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> dtest = pd.to_datetime("Sunday, July 28, 2018 10:00 AM", infer_datetime_format=True).replace(tzinfo=timezone('America/New_York')) # okay, this should uniquely represent a point in time
>>> dtest
Timestamp('2018-07-28 10:00:00-0400', tz='America/New_York') # yup, that's the time - 10AM at GMT-0400.
>>> dtest2 = dtest.tz_convert('UTC') # convert to UTC
>>> dtest2
Timestamp('2018-07-28 14:00:00+0000', tz='UTC') # yup, same point in time, just different time zone now
>>> dtest.strftime('%s') # let's convert to unix time - this looks right
'1532786400'
>>> dtest2.strftime('%s') # should be the same, but it's not. WTF?
'1532804400'
```

The timestamps look like they are describing things equivalently: one is 10 AM at GMT-0400, the other is 2 PM at GMT+0000, a difference of 4 hours of clock time, as expected.  They're both, of course, timezone-aware.  But then converting them to UNIX timestamps yields
(A) different numbers, and even worse,
(B) numbers that differ by 5 hours (18000 seconds = 5 * 60 * 60) rather than 4, so I can't even assume that strftime() is merely *ignoring* timezone.

I'm using https://www.epochconverter.com/ to validate any timestamps as I sanity-check this, so that's a possible point of being misled.  But according to that site,
1532786400 = 2018-07-28T10:00 -0400, and
1532804400 (that last result) = 2018-07-28T15:00 -0400, or 7pm GMT, a difference of 5 hours.

There are lots of questions on the subject of casting pandas Timestamps FROM a UNIX timestamp, but very little on questions casting TO epoch time.  I can think of 2 possible explanations:
(1) [tz_convert()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timestamp.tz_convert.html#pandas.Timestamp.tz_convert) is pulling some environment variable on my system that says I'm GMT -0500 and using that in the conversion process, in spite of that being irrelevant to converting between timezone-aware timestamps, and in so doing is actually changing the underlying point in time being represented. Or:
(2) Timestamp.strftime() is bugged and either ignoring the timezone parameter of a tz-aware timestamp or doing something truly bizarre when asked for a '%s' formatting parameter.

All advice greatly appreciated.